# Pass two variables to URL on page reload

Tags: php

On my page, I have two dropdown boxes: One for a list of dates, and one for options.  The box for dates is populated as such:

```
echo "<form name='selectedDate' action='page.php' method='GET' class='auto-style1'>";
echo "<select name='date' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
echo "<option value=select>Select a Date</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $date = date("m-d-Y",strtotime($row['date']));

    if($date==date("m-d-Y"))
    {
        echo "<option>TODAY</option>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option>" . $date . "</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<br />";          
echo "<noscript>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Select'>";
echo "</noscript>";
echo "</form>";
```

The other dropdown is populated as:

```
echo "<form name='selectedFormat' action='page.php' method='GET' class='auto-style1'>";
echo "<select name='option' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
echo "<option value=select>Select a Option</option>";
echo "<option value=Artist>Artist</option>";
echo "<option value=Song>Song</option>";
echo "</select>";

echo "<br />";          
echo "<noscript>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Select1'>";
echo "</noscript>";
echo "</form>";
```

Now, you notice that both of them are set for `Submit()` upon change. If I change the first one, the URL in the browser becomes `page.php?date=02-26-2013`, and if I change the second one, the URL in the browser becomes `page.php?option=Song`.

The problem that I'm having, is that if I change the `date` to an older date, and then change the `option`, my page reverts back to the `date` being the current date.  I've tried setting the action to a different URL:

```
$url = "musicInfo.php?date=" .  $nonFormatedDate . "&option=" . $option;
```

And I changed both forms to have:

```
echo "<form action='" . $url . "' method='GET' class='auto-style1'>";
```

If I `echo $url;`, it correctly displays what the browser URL should be.  However, the browser URL is still populated by whichever dropdown I used last.

My question here is, how do I get both variables to be passed upon either submission?

So for instance, if I change the `date` to be `01-13-2012`, and then change the `option` to `Song`, how can I ensure that the `date` will be passed as well?  And vice versa.  Or, say if I change the date to `01-12-2012`, is it possible to have the `date` dropdown box have this selected upon reload?

Site I'm trying to do:  http://www.legendary-immersion.com/random/test.php

Comment: You can only submit a single form at a time. You could try combining these forms into the same form, since they references the same `action`.

Comment: I understand that.  I edited my question a bit to show what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you submit a form, it will send only the form elements data from within itself to the `action` you have specified. I still see two forms above. As long as you have two separate forms, `GET` will not have data from the other without hijacking the `submit()` event and manually attaching it. Otherwise, PHP will never get the data from the other form.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like them to be two separate forms, and have them each reload the page.  Is there no way to share variables between them?

Comment: Not without using Javascript.

Comment: @TyrionLannister Is there a particular reason you want two form elements? The only reason to do this is to separate data input, whereas you clearly want the opposite.

Comment: @Asad: Because I want the user to be able to choose a `date`, and have page populated, and then they can choose `Artist/Song`, and have it stay on the same `date`.  Edited to show my site so you can understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @TyrionLannister This is what will happen if you use a single form. This will *not* happen if you use two separate forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people say in comment you can submit only one form per request.
So the best way is to hide data that you need in your form.

In your php file add this code

```
$date = isset($_GET["date"]) ? $_GET["date"] : "";
$option = isset($_GET["option"]) ? $_GET["option"] : "";
```

Then in first form add

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="<?php echo $option; ?>"/>
```

And in the second form add

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"/>
```

As the result in every form submit you will get the url like

```
page.php?date=yourdate&option=youroption
```

Best regards, Hope this will help